# Dictionary problem with aws lambda - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm developing an AWS lambda function with Python 3.6 and facing an odd scenario.

Locally, calling the function with  `python-lambda-local` everything works fine.

In AWS, the snippet below raises an exception:

```
def handler(event, context):
    data = event['body']
    logger.info("###DATAAAAA BODY " + str(data))
    origem = data.get('origem','')
```

**Error:**

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

It seems that, locally, the object **data** is a **dict**. But in AWS it is a **str**.

Comment: You've assigned `data` to be `event['body']`.  If that's a string, then you don't have a `.get()` method.  Perhaps log the entire contents of the event and double-check what you're receiving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the **@g.d.d.c** comment I could find the answer.

The problem is that `API Gateway` wrap the **body** value of the event with **quotes**.

So I have to parse it first to **dict**.

The correct code:

```
def handler(event, context):
    logger.info("###EVENT " + str(event))
    data = event.get('body')
    data = json.loads(data)
```